# Cannot install PyQt5 using Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, pyqt5

I am getting error when trying to install PyQt5 == 5.15.0 and am unsure what is causing the error.

```
(twitter) C:\Users\Neel Rajani\...\Documents\Twitter_F1\Test>pip install PyQt5==5.15.0
Collecting PyQt5==5.15.0
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.0.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Neel Rajani\anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Neel Rajani\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\conda_tmp\tmpktofpts8'
       cwd: C:\conda_tmp\pip-install-9hju2vvy\pyqt5_b9b9fb190de54fa1bd915ab94a7305b5
  Complete output (382 lines):
  Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
  "C:\Users\Neel Rajani\anaconda3\Library\bin\qmake.exe" -query
  This is the GPL version of PyQt 5.15.0 (licensed under the GNU General Public License) for Python 3.9.7 on win32.
  Found the license file 'pyqt-gpl.sip'.
  Checking to see if the QtCore bindings can be built...
  "C:\Users\Neel Rajani\anaconda3\Library\bin\qmake.exe" QtCore.pro
  Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Output:
```

I have reviewed other forums which suggested adding *cl.exe* to PATH which I have done, based on the path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe

However, the same error still appears

Comment: Try to find path of the cl.exe and run it without any args from your cmd.exe, is it running or not?

Comment: Hi Gautam, it is running from cmd: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30137 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]

Comment: can you modify your installation of Visual studio with all required components of C++ toolset and then retry. As this error shows that your MSVC compiler is not able to run from pip command. Also check your python is x86 or x64.

Comment: It worked however I hit another error: ` ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: C:\Users\Neel Rajani\anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Neel Rajani\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\conda_temp\tmp3qo6kaxd'
       cwd: C:\conda_temp\pip-install-c9bb_cq_\scipy_742b51e192314cf282f6af2696de0cba

Comment: Complete output (51 lines):
  setup.py:460: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base C:\conda_temp\pip-modern-metadata-5gn_yfxy'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
    warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
  Running from SciPy source directory.